# basic question to make a code with OMPL

Tags: ros, ompl, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read how to write a new global planner on this web.( http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS ).
and asked a question about how to implement OMPL. In the question, I said that OMPL is standalone. but, I don't make sense of standalone. I begin to write a code. Could anyone tell me if my description in ompl_planner_rrt.h is correct?
Thank you in advance!

ompl_planner_rrt.h

```
#ifndef OMPL_PLANNER_RRT_H_
#define OMPL_PLANNER_RRT_H_
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <nav_core/base_global_planner.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <angles/angles.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <base_local_planner/world_model.h>
#include <base_local_planner/costmap_model.h>
#include <ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/RRT.h>
```

ompl_planner_rrt.cpp

```
#include <ompl_planner_rrt/ompl_planner_rrt.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172889/basic-question-to-make-a-code-with-ompl/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-05**:
I should post this question on OMPL Mailing List?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-05**:
Above files are based on carrot_planner.cpp *.h. here I change namespace of carrot_planner to one of ompl_planner_rrt and I quoted CMakeLists.txt and package.xml in Problem with new BaseGlobalPlanner plugin. After catkin_make, it created libompl_planner_rrt.so. I don't use a function of ompl.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-05**:
It might be important for me to look through sample code of OMPL.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-05**:
I should edit  only makePlan in ompl_planner_rrt.cpp with ob = ompl;;base and og = ompl::geometric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Standalone means I can insert ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/RRT.h in ompl_planner_rrt.cpp and *.h and use function by calling OMPL.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0